# Efficiency of Qt Signals and Slots

Tags: c++, performance, qt4, game-engine, signals-slots

I was browsing the methods inside of QMainWindow and noticed that some parts (such as resizeEvent and winEvent) are not implemented as signals but rather you have to inherit this class to be able to override them.

My question is, how efficient are signals and slots and would it be possible to implement these types of functions as signals from which other classes can subscribe to. For instance, inside of a high performance game engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I recall, Trolltech stated that a signal/slot call is about 10 times slower than a `virtual` call. You should be able to easily process tens, if not hundreds of thousands signals per second.

Comment: Also signals/slots generates metadata, so it takes more memory for class instance, than virtual method. When calling singal (yes, signal is just a normal method) it goes through connected objects, and uses "invoke" method on recievers metaObject. It's slower than direct call of virtual method

Comment: So we wouldnt say there is any serious impact on realtime using signals and slots? Is there any reason we couldnt guarantee signals and slots to complete in a certain amount of time?

Comment: @ArmadilloChubbz65: It's still C++. Pass a one gigabyte string by value, and that copy will take serious time.

Answer (score 3):

Signal and slots are designed so that **different** objects can communicate, both objects being under your control.

The events you mention involve only **one** object at a time, which gets directly notified by the event loop. There is no need for signals or slots here.

Note that you can emit a signal inside an event member function if you want to. This is often the right way to react to an event. This way, other objects can subscribe to something.

Answer (score 0):

derive from QMainWindow, reimplement resize() and emit() signals from there, if you want to react on such signals at other places.

Comment: Or just create and install an event filter.